# How to prevent scanner from automatically writing into edit text when it has focus

Tags: android, android-edittext, barcode-scanner

When any edittext has focus the Scanner automatically writes the scanned data into focused edittext,Please check the .gif attached below which shows the actual concept.How can I prevent  the scanner from automatically writing the scanned data into the focused view.

I Tried dispatchKeyEvent() overridden method but it only gets called when I manually type on edittext.Also tried setting edittext editable only in touchmode using focusableInTouchMode = true but nothing  worked
Also the keyboard is set to hidden in manifest as well in activity.
the number that gets automatically written into edittext is due to scanning a Qr code.not from the keyboard

[image]

Comment: Please show the relevant scanner code

Comment: I don't have any scanning code. I simply added  only edit text in .xml file of my Activity and tried scanning than it writes automatically to the input views that has focus @cricket_007 i .e in my edittext

Comment: Then remove the focus or put it where you want the result.

Comment: Neither I put the scanned code by my own nor I m getting from any kind of code.I simply scan with my device and it does the thing

Comment: I don't know what that means. What are you scanning?

Comment: I have this device named XTIOT https://xtiot.en.alibaba.com/product/62028811920-814891995/XTIOT_XT8501_Warehouse_Inventory_Management_Handheld_Rugged_RFID_Barcode_Scanner_Industrial_Android_PDA.html?spm=a2700.icbuShop.41413.27.18db7f385SHSQz I simply open my messenger app and make its edit text focused and Scan any qr code or a bar code then it automatically gets filled into it.I want to prevent this thing in my App

Comment: Seems like a bug with the phone. If you can't prevent focus in an edittext, then dont see how you would disable the scanner